# Typesetting a band diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

Is there a way to typeset the following matrix in LaTeX?

[image]

In my attempt, I got to the following:

```
\begin{equation}
C=\left[\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
1 & 1  & 1 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & -1 & -1 & -1\\
1 & 1  & 1 & 1 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & -1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & \ldots   & 1 & 1 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & \ldots & \ldots  & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\hdotsfor{9}\cr\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots  \\
-1 &0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & -1 & -1 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}
```

Would like to know how to add the curly braces.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125123/are-there-specialized-libraries-or-packages-to-draw-blocked-partitioned-splittin

Answer (score 3):

You can take as preview this example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\underbrace{%
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3& 0 \\
   1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 & 1 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 4 & 3& 3 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 3 & 16 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 4 & & 4 & 0 & 6 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
}_{\mathrm{bla\,\,bla\,\, bla}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

or see at the link [braces over matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130798/braces-over-matrix).